# OpenFileDialog keep showing .lnk files WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, openfiledialog

Is it possible to force OpenFileDialog not to show shortcuts?

I only want to get pdf, so I'm using the filter like this

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
   Multiselect = false,
   Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf"
};
```

But when the dialog is shown, it shows files with `pdf` extension **and** `lnk` extension

[image: example image]

Is it possible to prevent it?

Comment: Not out of the box, no. [Have a look at this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/711ef1d3-0e5f-4836-804a-78402ea8bccc/why-does-openfiledialog-contain-shortcuts-to-noncsv-files?forum=vbgeneral) - you'll have to write a custom OpenFileDialog. The reason is, as mentioned in the post too, that a user could use a `.lnk` to navigate to another folder.

Comment: @nilsK ty, can you post that as answer? so i mark it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer is from the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/711ef1d3-0e5f-4836-804a-78402ea8bccc/why-does-openfiledialog-contain-shortcuts-to-noncsv-files?forum=vbgeneral)

Out of the box the OpenFileDialog is not able to do that.
A reason might be, that `.lnk` files could be used by a user, to navigate to a different folder, where he/she expects the file, that needs to be opened.

In the above posted link the user 'Ryan' posted a snippet, to exclude selected  `.lnk` files in the `FileOK` event.

Again, not my code! But since some websites move their content and a link might not work any longer, here 'Ryan's' code snippet (written in VB):

```
Public Class Home

    Private WithEvents _fileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    Private Sub BrowseButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton1.Click
        With Me._fileDialog
            .DereferenceLinks = True    ' this allows the FileName property to have the Target of a shortcut link, instead of the shortcut link file name
            .Multiselect = False
            .Filter = "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)|*.csv"
            .ShowDialog()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub _fileDialog_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles _fileDialog.FileOk
        If Not Me._fileDialog.FileName Like "*.csv" Then
            ' cancel any shortcut files here
            e.Cancel = True
            MsgBox("You must select a CSV (Comma delimited) file.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.Text = Me._fileDialog.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the reason you don't want to show `.lnk` files is because you want the path to the actual PDF file? If so, you should be able to set the [`DereferenceLinks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.dereferencelinks?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Win32_FileDialog_DereferenceLinks) property to `true`. If the user selects a `.lnk` file, the dialog will return the path to the file the `.lnk` file points to rather than the `.lnk` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a Open file dialog to hide specific files. The only thing you can do is Use the **Filter** tag to filter specified file extension for saving purpose but not hiding.

Answer (score -1):

I.E. on save dialog I use it like this for excel files.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

So, with open file dialog should be the same.

Comment: Ty for you time, I set the three properties and the shortcuts continue being visible :(